# Proper and accurate way to back up in a folder, the hole System

Tags: command-line, backup, directory, rsync, restore

What is the most accurate and safe way to backup the hole System (all the `/` directory) on ubuntu?

I am new to Linux, and I am running Ubuntu Server 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi, and I want to backup everything in a folder, could  be here for example: `/home/me/backupsFolder`

I am looking for a safe and accurate way to do this. Many reccomends using `rsync` others `tar`. I would appreciate if you avoid giving solutions like creating a bootable image into a USB, or using, only GUI based tools, due to my set-up.

Please, also provide the reverse process: say the system fails, or get corrupted... or you just want to restore it back to certain point, and you keep this folder `/home/me/backupsFolder`, what is the proper way to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't know if it is the most or second/third or twenty third most, but it's a way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR.

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem